# Cannot trigger a click on a button on mobile phones (Code and link included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

Can someone explain to me why this add to cart button isn't working on mobile devices?

It's not even triggering a click, I'm not getting the alert popup.

It wasn't working with `"click"` so I changed to `"click touchstart"` (I know it's not an ideal solution) but I just wanted to be able to trigger the js.

No success.

It's an `<a>` tag which triggers a jquery function, works fine on all browsers but not on mobile.

Here's the javascript code:

```
$('body').on('click touchstart', '.add-to-cart', function(){
  alert("click");
  //other code...
 });
```

The code off the button is:

```
<a href="#" class="add-to-cart">Add to cart<i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i></a>
```

[Link to live example](http://www.aplikacija1.com.hr/kolekcija/proizvod-1482-sandale-2003-camel)

Hope you guys can help me, any tip in the possible direction is valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax and code is fine, but there is an error in your cartManipulation.init function:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pa_cart' of null

and the event handler goes never initialized.

BTW, i suggest you also to put href="javascript: void(0)" instead of href="#" in the dummy link, or much better, switch to buttons.